# how to show result of query in listbox in Wpf

Tags: wpf

I want to show result of query into listbox in corecct format
I am triyng now, but the result is not true and my code show the name of object on my screen.
after that I add ".tostring()" after my code but the result still wrong and i really counfused about that.

```
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT OprUser FROM Register WHERE  OprUser    LIKE'%" +txt_owner.Text.ToString() + "%' GROUP BY OprUser");
                conn.Open();
                lstowner.Items.Remove(txt_owner.Text);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable rows = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(rows);
                int count = rows.Rows.Count;
                if (count > 0)
                { 
                    lstowner.Items.Clear();
                    lstowner.Items.Add(rows.Rows["OprUser"].ToString());
                }
                conn.Close();
```

I am expecting that the result of query shows in correct format.

Answer (score -2):

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT OprUser FROM Register WHERE  OprUser LIKE '%" + txt_owner.Text.ToString() + "%' GROUP BY OprUser");
                conn.Open();
                lstowner.Items.Remove(txt_owner.Text);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable rows = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(rows);
                int count = rows.Rows.Count;
                if (count > 0)
                {
                   
                    lstowner.Items.Clear();

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        lstowner.Items.Add(rows.Rows[i]["OprUser"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).